# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Injection of autowired dependencies

Tags: spring, autowired

Can any one solve this
 i am getting the below error which runs on eclipse

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested
 exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.spring.service.CustomerService
 com.spring.controller.PersonController.customerService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
 'customerService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.spring.repository.CustomerRepository com.spring.service.CustomerServiceImpl.customerRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.spring.repository.CustomerRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

i have the following

```
1.PersonController (class)
2.Person (class)
3.CustomerService (interface)
4.CustomerServiceImpl (class)
5.CustomerRepository (interface)

package com.spring.controller
in PersonController (class)
=====================
    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public String getPersonList(ModelMap model) {  
        model.addAttribute("personList", customerService.findAlls());  
        return "output";  
    }

package com.spring.service
in CustomerService (interface)
==================
    public List<Person> findAlls();


package com.spring.service
in CustomerServiceImpl
=====================

@Service("customerService")
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;


    public List<Person> findAlls() {
        List<Person> usersList = customerRepository.findAll();
        return null;

    }

}

package com.spring.repository
in CustomerRepository
===========================

@Repository("customerRepository")
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {

    public List<Person> findAll();

}
```

thanks and regards

Comment: Where is the implementation class of the CustomerRepository ??

Comment: i am using mongodb i thing it will go to it super implementation MongoRepository . and findAll() is a built in function . i dont know it is correct or not

Comment: No matching bean of type [com.spring.repository.CustomerRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)} You are trying to autowire CustomerRepository which is creating  problem

Comment: Thanks Deepak for your comment. I am new to spring. then what i have to do to use CustomerRepository ,I saw a code like this autowire CustomerRepository .

Comment: As Deepak says, something in Spring's application context must implement the `CustomerRepository` interface so that Spring can find it and then autowire it into the `customerRepository` field. Typically this would be called something like `CustomerRepositoryImpl` which would be annotated `@Repository`.

Comment: thanks for your comments, can i use query directly in CustomerRepository like my code without CustomerRepositoryImpl ? is there any other way.

Comment: as Will Keeling said I created CustomerRepositoryImpl. from that how i can access mongodb
I tried to @Autowire  MongoRepository it showing same error
how i can access mongodb from CustomerRepositoryImpl

 
public interface CustomerRepository  {
  public List<Person> findAll();
}

 
@Service("customerRepository")
public   class CustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerRepository {
  
 public List<Person> findAll(){
 return null;
  }
 }  Thanks